# AngularJS передать переменную с директивы в TemplateUrl

Tags: angularjs, переменные, шаблоны

Есть кнопка, при нажатии на нее в тег  как в родительский добавляется некий html блок. Этот блок выводится с помощью моей директивы:

```
        <ol id="optionsList" class="inputs">
            <answer-field option="1"/>
        </ol>
```

Вот сама директива:

```
.directive('answerField', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var id = attrs["option"];
        },
        templateUrl: 'template.html' 
    }
})
```

И шаблон

```
<li>
    <input class="testVariant" type="text" name="option**N**" required/>
</li>
```

Так вот при нажатии кнопки ng-click в контролере, я добавляю в конец 
`<ol>` элементы `<li>` с шаблона с помощью директивы и компилирую(шаблон сложнее чем в примере и с другими директивами).

Проблема: как сделать чтобы шаблоны генерировались с передаваемыми им переменными, например чтобы вместо **N** подставляло значение option из `<answer-field option="N"/>`

Пока решил вопрос используя только template вместо templateURL:

```
.directive('answerField', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: function (elm, attrs) {
            return '<li><input class="testVariant" type="text" ' +
                'name="option' + attrs["option"] + '" id="option' + attrs["option"] + '" size="80" required/>' +
                '<div ng-click="alert()" class="ckeImg">CKE</div><div class="answerCheck" inline-block">' +
                '<div id="answersList" class="answersCheckbox"><div><input type="checkbox" ' +
                'name="answer' + attrs["option"] + '" value=' + attrs["option"] + '></div></div></div></li>'
        },
    }
})
```

Но это не красиво и наверно не правильно. Или как в шаблоне считать каким по индексу является экземпляр шаблона в родительском контейнере(списку)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В темплейте доступен `scope` директивы. Просто добавьте это свойство в scope и используйте

```
.directive('answerField', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true, //чтобы не засорять родительский скоп
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.id = attrs["option"];
        },
        templateUrl: 'template.html' 
    }
})
```

так же можно использовать изолированный скоп

```
.directive('answerField', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            id: '@option'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) { // в принципе теперь данную функцию можно удалить из этого объекта
        },
        templateUrl: 'template.html' 
    }
})
```

в шаблоне, например так

```
<li>
    <input class="testVariant" type="text" name="option{{id}}" required/>
</li>
```

Comment: Благодарю! То что и нужно